# Having trouble with JS object literal setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, object

So I've setup my first JS design pattern - but I've run into an issue.

Here is my code on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jrutter/CtMNX/

```
var emailSignup = {
'config': {
    // Configurable Options
    'container': $('#email-signup'),
    'emailButton': $('#email-submit'),
    'emailInput': $('#email-input'),
    'brontoDirectAddURL': 'URL',
    'brontoListID': '0bbc03ec000000000000000000000003287b',

},
'init': function (config) {
    // stays the same
    // provide for custom configuration via init()
    if (config && typeof (config) == 'object') {
        $.extend(emailSignup.config, config);
    }
        // Create and/or cache some DOM elements
       emailSignup.$container = $(emailSignup.config.container);
emailSignup.$button = $(emailSignup.config.emailButton);
emailSignup.$input = $(emailSignup.config.emailInput);
emailSignup.$brontoURL = emailSignup.config.brontoDirectAddURL;
emailSignup.$brontoList = emailSignup.config.brontoListID;

    // Add email track to drop image pixel into for submission
    emailSignup.$container.append('<div class="email-error"></div>');
    emailSignup.$container.append('<div class="email-track"></div>');

    // Call getEmaile
    emailSignup.getEmail(emailSignup.$button, emailSignup.$input);

    // make a note that the initialization is complete
    emailSignup.initialized = true;

},
'getEmail': function ($button, $input) {

    // click event
    emailSignup.$button.click(function () {
        // get the val
        var $emailVal = $(emailSignup.$input).val();
        // Call validateEmail
        console.log($emailVal);
        emailSignup.validateEmail($emailVal);

        return false;
    });

},
'validateEmail': function ($emailVal) {

    var $emailRegEx = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    //console.log($emailVal);

    if ($emailVal == '') {
        $(".email-error").html('<p>You forgot to enter an email address.</p>');
    } else if (!$emailRegEx.test($emailVal)) {
        $(".email-error").html('<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>');
    } else {
        $(".email-error").hide();
        emailSignup.submitEmail($emailVal);
    }


},
'submitEmail': function ($emailVal) {
    $(".email-track").html('<img src=' + emailSignup.$brontoURL+'&email='+$emailVal+'&list1=' + emailSignup.$brontoList + '" width="0" height="0" border="0" alt=""/>');
},
```

};

Its a function to add a subscriber to an email list via bronto - it works perfectly when the script is included on the page and the init function is setup on the page too. But when I include the script in a shared header and try to fire the function from the document-ready, it doesnt seem to be working.

Also, if I try to pass in a 'container' - that also is breaking the script. Not sure what Im doing wrong? But if I pass in the URL - that does work!

```
$(function () {
     emailSignup.init({
       'brontoDirectAddURL':'URL','container':'#email-signup'
        });
});
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors. I get an error when I click on the Submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code...

```
emailSignup.$container = emailSignup.config.container;
emailSignup.$button = emailSignup.config.emailButton;
emailSignup.$input = emailSignup.config.emailInput;
emailSignup.$brontoURL = emailSignup.config.brontoDirectAddURL;
emailSignup.$brontoList = emailSignup.config.brontoListID;
```

into the following...

```
// Create and/or cache some DOM elements
emailSignup.$container = $(emailSignup.config.container);
emailSignup.$button = $(emailSignup.config.emailButton);
emailSignup.$input = $(emailSignup.config.emailInput);
emailSignup.$brontoURL = $(emailSignup.config.brontoDirectAddURL);
emailSignup.$brontoList = $(emailSignup.config.brontoListID);

// Add email track to drop image pixel into for submission
emailSignup.$container.append('<div class="email-error"></div>');
emailSignup.$container.append('<div class="email-track"></div>');
```

You can not call append on a string. I've update your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtMNX/29/).

Comment: Ok - That seemed to work - except the brontoURL and brontoList were left as is - as they arent DOM elements. They are variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your default config object contains jQuery collections. However, you are simply passing the string `"#email-signup"` as your `container` instead of `$("#email-signup")`. That's where the error is coming from. Your initial call should thusly be:

```
$(function () {
    emailSignup.init({
        'brontoDirectAddURL':'URL','container': $('#email-signup')
    });
});
```

Note that as your initial module includes some jQuery calls, you will need to wrap the whole `emailSignup` mess into a `$(document).ready()` as well.

You may consider reconfiguring this whole thing as a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Thanks - so the module will need to be wrapped too? I was trying to get away from wrapping everything in a jQuery ready event - but I guess its because Ive used jQuery in my module? I see.

Comment: In this example, Rebecca Murphy only drops the init into a document.ready event: http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code/ - Why doesnt that work for me in the page?

Comment: @jrutter in her case, the default `config` object only contains strings, not full jQuery objects. If you store yours the same way, you can get away with it, but as it stands you have jQuery statements which will be executed as soon as that module loads.

Comment: In her default config - she is loading a jQuery object. 'container' : $('#myFeature'), - So how is that different?

Comment: @jrutter hmm, curious. I suppose if it's loaded at the end of the document you could get lucky. I'd still recommend deferring any jQuery executions until after the `ready` event.